# Changing Javascript source URL based on interface translation

Tags: javascript, caching, drupal-8

I've run into a particularly troubling issue when trying to attach external libraries which URL changes based on the translation of the site.

To sketch the situation:

There's an element on a website I'm working on which loads in an external Javascript file to display certain contents.
This element is only shown on a specific page rendered by a module.

The languages are noted by subdomain, for example: uk.example.com, de.example.com

The script should be loaded based on this subdomain, so: uk.example.com/script.js, de.example.com/script.js , The path will always be the same.

The problem I'm running into:

While attaching the Javascript using a `HOOK_library_info_alter()` the Javascript source URL gets cached, this means that the `uk` version of the script gets loaded in on de `de` version of the site. It's not possible to change this system, these scripts need to be loaded using different URLs for reasons I wont go in.

I've tried adding the script using a `HOOK_page_attachments` to put the script in the header with the correct subdomain, except it is impossible to determine if the script only gets loaded on that specific page, with that specific element (Using `library_info_alter` I'm able to check if the `$extension` is correct)

Is there any possible solution to this problem?

I'm sorry if it's worded problematic, my english isn't exactly amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the outline of a possible solution:

```
function yourmodule_page_attachments(array &$page) {

  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();

  if($current_path == '/node/123') {
    if($language == 'en') {
      $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'yourmodule/extlib-en';
    }
  }
}
```

You will need to change "yourmodule", "/node/123" and "en" to fit, obviously, and define "extlib-en" and other language-specific libraries in `yourmodule.liraries.yml`, as defined in [Drupal 8 documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-module#external).